# How to regenerate an apk?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

This morning I generated an `apk` via this command:

`./gradlew bundleRelease`

which generated the following:

[image]

However, now I need to generate a newer version of the `apk` as I made some changes to the application.

I tried just running the above command again, but that did not seem to work. The files are all the same ones. How do I regenerate an `apk`? Do I need to delete the old ones first?

Comment: Are you trying to generate a bundle (what `bundleRelease` does) or an APK (what `assembleRelease` does)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake, I am trying to generate an `apk`. I followed this guide: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android#generating-the-release-apk

Comment: @ianhanniballake, why doesn't the facebook docs make that clear? It did generate an `apk` directory.

Comment: It appears that you can [file documentation bugs](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/new?labels=Type%3A+Docs&template=documentation.md&title=Docs%3A) - that's probably the best way to get the documentation updated to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clean your older build first using

```
./gradlew clean
```

Then build your apk using

```
# for debug
./gradlew assembleDebug

# for release
./gradlew assembleRelease

# if you want all the build variants, just using below command
./gradlew assemble
```

Your apks can be found inside `output/apk` directory

Answer (score 1):

`bundleRelease` generates a bundle - filing in just the `bundle` directory you see. You should be using `assembleRelease` if you want to generate an APK and the `apk` directory:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```